# Why do I lose my instance information when calling a prototype function via setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I think I'm missing some key concept regarding objects and prototype functions in JavaScript.

I have the following:

```
function Bouncer(ctx, numBalls) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.numBalls = numBalls;
    this.balls = undefined;
}

Bouncer.prototype.init = function() {
    var randBalls = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.numBalls; i++) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*400+1);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400+1);
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+5);
        randBalls.push(new Ball(x, y, 15, "#FF0000"));
    }
    this.balls = randBalls;
    this.step();
}

Bouncer.prototype.render = function() { 
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);  
    for(var i = 0; i < this.balls.length; i++) {
        this.balls[i].render(this.ctx);
    }
}

Bouncer.prototype.step = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.balls.length; i++) {
        this.balls[i].yPos -= 1;
    }      
    this.render();
    setTimeout(this.step, 1000);
}
```

I then create an instance of Bouncer and call its init function like so:

```
$(function() {
    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var width = $('#canvas').width();
    var height = $('#canvas').height();



    var bouncer = new Bouncer(ctx, 30);
    bouncer.init();
});
```

The init() function will call step which has a setTimeout to loop the step function.

This works on the first call to step().  However, on the second call (when setTimeout fires step) the instance variable "balls" is undefined.  So, in my step function, the second call will blow up saying there is no "length" property for undefined.

Why do I lose my instance information when calling step from setTimeout()?

How could I restructure this so I can loop via a timeout and still have access to those instance variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout(this.step, 1000);`, the `step` method loses its desired context of `this`, as you're passing a reference to the `step` method. In the way that you're doing it now, when `this.step` gets called through `setTimeout`, `this === window` rather than your `Bouncer` instance.

This is easy to fix; just use an anonymous function, and keep a reference to `this`:

```
Bouncer.prototype.step = function() {
    var that = this; // keep a reference
    for(var i = 0; i < this.balls.length; i++) {
        this.balls[i].yPos -= 1;
    }      
    this.render();
    setTimeout(function () { 
        that.step()
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds, and with a neater example to boot. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a Javascript function, the value of `this` is determined by the *call site*.

When you pass `this.step` to `setTimeout`, the `this` is not magically preserved; it just passes the `step` function itself.
`setTimeout` calls its callback with `this` as `window`.

You need to create a closure that calls `step` on the right object:

```
var me = this;
setTimeout(function() { me.step(); }, 500);
```

For more information on the difference between `this` and closures, [see my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/07/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-5.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly standard 'this' scope issues.  Many, many questions on SO regarding mis-understanding the context of 'this' when executing functions.  I recommend you read-up on it.

However, to answer your question, it works because you are *calling* this.step(), and 'this', in that context, is your desired Bouncer instance.

The second (and subsequent) times it does *not* work, because when you specify a function to be invoked by setTimeout, it is invoked by the 'window' context.  This is because you are passing a reference to the step function, and context is not included in that reference.

Instead, you can maintain context by calling it from the correct scope, from inside an anonymous method:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){ self.step(); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that anything executed by setTimeout happens in global scope, so the reference to `this` no longer points to your function, it points to `window`.

To fix it, just cache `this` as a local variable inside step, then reference that variable in your setTimeout call:

```
Bouncer.prototype.step = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.balls.length; i++) {
        this.balls[i].yPos -= 1;
    }      
    this.render();
    var stepCache = this;
    setTimeout(function () { stepCache.step() }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others pointed out the calling context issues, but here's a different solution:

```
setTimeout( this.step.bind( this ), 1000 );
```

This uses [the ECMAScript 5 `bind()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method  to send a function with the calling context bound to whatever you pass as the first argument.

---

If support for JS environments that don't support `.bind()` is needed, the documentation link I provided gives a solution that will be sufficient for most cases.

*From the docs:*

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== "function") // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
        throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be fBound is not callable");
        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
            fToBind = this,
            fNOP = function () {},
            fBound = function () {
                return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis || window, aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
        return fBound;
    };
}
```

This will add the `.bind()` shim to all functions via `Function.prototype` if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a closure issue as indicated by @SLaks.

Try this:

```
Bouncer.prototype.step = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.balls.length; i++) {
        this.balls[i].yPos -= 1;
    }      
    var self = this;
    this.render();
    setTimeout(function() {self.step();}, 1000);
}
```